# Insert Values to Database Where Users= Input

Tags: c#, mysql

I have form1 and form2. Form1 is Login and Form2 is Main Menu.
I am using (C# Access), and I have fields in my database, Here are my fields (Users, Pass, Player1, Player2).

Now, I want to insert values in  player1 and player2 fields to the database with its corresponding Users field.

Note: Users is username.

How to do that? Please help me.

Here's my current code

```
Form1 f2 = new Form1();
            f2.ShowDialog();
           MessageBox.Show(f2.getTextBoxVal());//This is just a test in getting the Username from Form1 which is the Login form
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connParam))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from data where Users = ?"))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player1score", player1score);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player2score", player2score);
                object objRes = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (objRes == null || (int)objRes == 0)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (Player1,Player2) values(?, ?) WHERE Users='" + f2.getTextBoxVal() + "')";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player1score", player1score.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player2score", player2score.Text);
                    int iRes = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Error Here It says Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.

                    if (iRes > 0)
                        //errorProvider2.SetError(textBox1, "");
                        //errorProvider3.SetError(textBox1, "User name available!");
                        MessageBox.Show("Scores Save!!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Just a Test!");
                }

                }
```

In form1 I use to have this code :

```
public string getTextBoxVal()
{
   return textBox1.Text;
}
```

This is for getting the text in form1

In form 2 I use to have this code:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();
MessageBox.Show( f2.getTextBoxVal());
```

This is my way to retrieve textbox val using  **getTextBoxVal()**  function from **Form1* :

And I use it here:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (Player1,Player2) values(?, ?) WHERE Users='" + f2.getTextBoxVal() + "')";
```

However, I cant save the values to the particular username or account that I use to Login.

How to fix this please?

Comment: You should be using a property instead of using a method to get the value of `textBox1.Text` from the form e.g. `public string Textbox1Text { get { return textBox1.Text; } }`. Don't construct queries from unsanitized user input either e.g. `WHERE Users = '" + userinput + "'";` as this leaves you vulnerable to injection based exploits.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` does not support or even need `WHERE`

You don't need it and need to adjust your query accordingly.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (Player1,Player2) values(?, ?)";
```

INSERT is about adding new entries to the table. If you want to update, please use the UPDATE command. That command supports 'WHERE'.

UPDATE typically looks something like:

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2' ...
 WHERE id = id_value
```

Furthermore, your first use of `cmd` doesn't seem right to me.
You pass two playerscores, where only one Username is required.

Comment: But then it didn't inserted the values to its corresponding Username. On the other hand, it inserted in the next rows in the database access

Comment: Sir I think it's right, I need an update not insert, Can you help me sir?

Comment: I am also not sure about your database design. You should probably have different tables for users/passwords and matches.